# Integrate CHARGEBEE library to LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, chargebee

Im starting using LARAVEL last version 7.12 and I'm having an issue trying to integrate *CHARGEBEE* library to make request to *Chargebee api*.

I was reading that I can install packages with composer, I did it:

```
composer require chargebee/chargebee-php:'>=2, <3'
```

Doing that now I have downloaded *chargebee lib* here: `/vendor/chargebee/chargebee-php/`

Now also I saw [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346680/how-to-require-and-configure-a-dependency-in-laravel) stack overflow question here:

That for the user to correctly use this Library-Package I need to create a `ServiceProvider` so I did:

```
 php artisan make:provider ChargeBeeServiceProvider
```

then I really don't know how to write the `REGISTER()` function here, I added also this line: `App\Providers\ChargebeeServiceProvider::class,` to `/config/app.php` to `'providers'`

[ChargebeeServiceProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQxLR.png)

Right now I have a controller: `/app/http/controllers/PortalController` and I'm trying to use this:

```
ChargeBee_Environment::configure("sitename","apikeyvalue"); 

$all = ChargeBee_Customer::all(array( "firstName[is]" => "John", 
"lastName[is]" => "Doe", "email[is]" => "john@test.com" ));

foreach($all as $entry){
  $customer = $entry->customer();
  $card = $entry->card(); 
}
```

[PortalController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg8L8.png)

**BUT** on the frontend it's giving me an error:

> Error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ChargeBee_Customer' not found

Not really sure how i can use this custom *Chargebee* library here on Laravel.

can somebody please help to integrate in the correct way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that `ChargeBee_Environment` class doesn't exists.

It should be `Chargebee\ChargeBee\Environment`. And the Models are in their own folder, for example the Portal is `ChargeBee\ChargeBee\Models\PortalSession`

WPTC-Troop's answer provides some great information on the issue of using a service provider vs library directly, but in the end you need to call the correct classes.

My working code for creating a portal session is below. It would be similar for a Customer object:

```
    \ChargeBee\ChargeBee\Environment::configure("test-site","test_api_key");
    $result = \ChargeBee\ChargeBee\Models\PortalSession::create(["customer" => ["id" => "AzZlwTSSVw9871E9g"]]);
    $portalSession = $result->portalSession();
    $output = $portalSession->getValues();
    
    return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things, you can use any third party library as Service Provider(DI) in Laravel or use it directly where ever you needed(mostly in controller)

Not just third party library you can ease the instance creation of class etc in Service Provider. Basically it's for dependency injection, Check [IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) in general you'll understand it better.

You tried/mixed both in your case and didn't completely use any single approach.

1. You've created a Service Provider called `ChargeBeeServiceProvider` but it doesn't return/bind any resource or no API initialization done in `register` method. This is where you register and make use of DI. You can bind in properties as well. Here is the [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers) to it.
2. You tried to use directly by initializing `ChargeBee_Environment` and use `ChargeBee_Customer` but you didn't mention where to look for this class that is the reason you get the error(Error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ChargeBee_Customer' not found). I mean compiler will look for `ChargeBee_Environment` from the same local space but `ChargeBee_Environment` is available from global scope.

Simple solution to your same code. Add `\` to the class to look from global scope or make use of `use` statement in the top of your file similar to import in java but still we need to require/include the file in php but don't worry, chargebee make use of autoloader(Check here -> [composer.json](https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-php/blob/master/composer.json#L9)) so it will be loaded automatically in both approach.

```
\ChargeBee_Environment::configure("sitename","apikeyvalue"); 

$all = \ChargeBee_Customer::all(array( "firstName[is]" => "John", 
"lastName[is]" => "Doe", "email[is]" => "john@test.com" ));
```

Try the above and let me know. Answered from mobile device. Code is not tested fully(Just copied your and added `\` to it).

Excuse brevity :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to use ChargeBee and Laravel. Don't need any: register provider, add to aliases or add path to autoload in composer.json by file path. Just add in `use` classes that you need in code your Service or your Controller. Like `use ChargeBee_Environment` and other.

```
use ChargeBee_Environment;
use ChargeBee_Customer;

ChargeBee_Environment::configure("sitename","apikeyvalue");
$all = ChargeBee_Customer::all(array( "firstName[is]" => "John", "lastName[is]" => "Doe", "email[is]" => "john@test.com" ));
foreach($all as $entry){
  $customer = $entry->customer();
  $card = $entry->card();
}
```